# Background image cover behaves different on mobile Chrome

Tags: html, css

We are trying to have a fixed background image that covers the entire viewport for our content (so like a wallpaper where the content floats on top of). Here is code that I've always used to accomplish this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div>
</div>

<style>
div {

height: 150vh; 

background: url(https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2019/spring-equinox-2019-northern-hemisphere-5139135894388736.3-l.png) no-repeat center fixed;
background-size: cover;

}
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

You can also view it here: http://neonorb.com/background-test.html

On desktop Chromium and Firefox as well as mobile Firefox, this behaves as I would expect. That is, the container is 150vh and you can scroll as such while the background image remains still.

However, if you view it in mobile Chrome, the image takes up the full height of its container (i.e. 150vh) and actually scrolls and is not fixed.

Is this a bug in mobile Chrome? Or is this behavior actually correct and the bug actually resides in desktop Chromium and both Firefoxes? Or am I doing something wrong?

*Edit:*

Doing some research into the behavior of `background-size:cover;`... It says that [`cover`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#valdef-background-size-cover) only covers the ["background positioning area"](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#background-positioning-area). And by itself this is fine.

However, when you also apply [`background-attachment:fixed;`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#valdef-background-attachment-fixed) the image is treated as a `position:fixed;` instead.

So why does it seem that most browsers cover the entire viewport like this, but mobile Chrome does not?

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on applying the background to a div, and not the body element itself; make sure that your div remains the same size as the viewport (or area you want the background to cover):

```
#div-with-background {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;

    background: url(https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2019/spring-equinox-2019-northern-hemisphere-5139135894388736.3-l.png) no-repeat center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You'll also want to remove the margin(s) on the html and body tags:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ne95d4za/

Comment: To add to this answer make the body have the background image and apply the css to the body

Answer (score 0):

You will see the same "error" on mobile Safari. Actually it is even worse, as Chrome automatically sets the background size on cover, Safari doesn't.

I think the reason to deactivate that is to avoid errors on touchscreens, wich had problems with fixed elements.

I haven't found a solution without using a parallax effect but would be happy to know how to solve that issue.